Strange collision behavior between active and passive rigid bodies, based on the number of active body duplicates
EDIT: For now I'm going to try to create this motion using drivers, custom properties and control meshes instead, with more advanced distance based calculations. Hopefully I can have more control on the set-up without having to rely on collisions. I will leave this post up for a while in case someone finds themselves in a similar situation as I previously did.

EDIT2: A temporary solution I've found to the original set-up is to reapply the same rigid body property to body A AFTER duplicating body B. I'm going to make a before-and-after duplicate of the project file and try to analyze its contents and python data to see what exactly changes when I do this. At first glance the two are the exact same project.

I'm having issues with a rigid body that needs to collide with a passive body but it doesn't work well once duplicated. Project's purpose is an animation.
An animated rigid body A is pushing down on an active rigid body B, which should be stopped by a passive rigid body C underneath, acting as a bed.
The rigid body B is constrained to a hinge and a spring: the hinge is connected to a passive rigid body in the back, and the spring is connected to the passive rigid body C underneath.

The collision runs as I expect (the animated body A pushes B down and it hits C, stopping it fully).

The issue:
When I duplicate the rigid body B along with its constraints, the collision with the rigid body C becomes spongy and unpredictable as they pass through each other.

One of them ignores the collision with the static body C.

With 2 duplicates it seems to collide properly for some reason.

With 3 duplicates 3 of the bodies go through (including the original).

With each duplicate added, the behavior repeats in a new random order.
Things that I've tried so far that failed to change their behavior (with a fresh load of the file for each):

I've added a completely separate passive body between the original C and the duplicates as a bed (thinking there was an issue with the passive body C being used as a link for the spring constrain of the object it had to collide with).

I've used a separate body C for each duplicate as a bed (thinking there's an issue with the passive body C being used as a common constraint link for all duplicates).

I've used only 1 hinge instead of 2 (either of them).

I've experimented with various collision shapes, masses and constraint values/limits.


Extra info:

It happens with both Shift + D, Copy + paste, AND with completely new rigid bodies made from scratch instead of duplicates.
Transforms are applied on all of them.
Simulation substeps and iterations: 100 - 400. The change is inconsequential
The .blend file is fresh (only these objects have been added).
Tested on 3.6 LTS, 4.1, 4.2.

Streamable video demo
Project .blend file
